# Questions about deflection coil interlock on CRT TVs to restore beam brightness control

Tags: hacking, crt

[image: Circuit diagram of minivision 100TV]Electronics noob here, with experience in science and research. I am trying to make a music visulaiser out of an old monochrome CRT TV by connecting the horizontal and vertical deflection coils to an amplifier as documented elsewhere.

https://crackedraytube.com/pdfs/oscillographic_tv_tutorial.pdf

Firstly, I have been taking proper safety precautions of discgharging the CRT before working on it and I am aware of the danger.

When I cut the wires to the horizontal and vertical deflection coils I am left with a very faint dot in the middle of the screen. The brightness of this dot cannot be controlled by the brightness pot for the TV and the brightness is too low to get the desired effect. I have read in forums that the horizontal deflection coil circuitry is used along with the flyback transformer to help create the high voltage required for the electron gun so disconnecting it will cause the beam to not work. Separately I read that there is some safety interlock when you disconnect the coils which prevents the beam turning on. In the above tutorial the creator used high power ceramic resistors with a similar impedance to the deflection coils to trick this circuitry into thinking the coils were connected. I measured the resistance of my coils using a multimeter to be 5 and 0.4 ohms each and purchased 6.8 ohm (11 W) and 0.68 ohm (4 W) resistors to replicate them as that was what was readily available and I was not sure of the sensitivity of the detection mechanism or the exact operational mechanism. In this case when they were connected there was not even a dot in the middle of the screen and the 6.8 ohm resistor got extremely hot (I guess I need a higher power resistor to solve that). However, I would like to understand what is going wrong before I start a trial and error process with lots of resistors which can be expensive to order or require a long trip across town to a specialist shop that's only open on weekdays. The problem is definitely with the horizontal coil I tried all different configs of 1 resistor, 2 resitors or no resistors and it doesn't care what the vertical coil does. Reconnecting of the deflection coils causes the TV to go back to normal with brightness being able to be controlled.

My current thinking with this situation is the horizontal deflection coil/circuitry is responsible for boosting the input voltage to the flyback transformer which results in a low brightness dot when disconnected. However I don't understand why the addition of the resistor doesnt result in this same dot appearing.

I have included a picture of the circuit diagram. The TV is a Minivision 100T which has the same circuitry as the Calypso TVP-2770

Now to my questions:

1. Is what is happening due to a safety interlock or is the actual deflection coil itself integral in the boosting of the gun voltage.
2. Why didn't my resistor hack work, is the detection circuitry very sensitive so I need to get precisely the correct value for the impedance?
3. If it is an interlock, what type of circuit would that be so I can try and locate it on the board and would it be possible and safe to bypass it? Personally I think it would much more elegant to bypass the deflection circuit all together rather than just dump it all as heat into resistors.

Thanking you in advanced for any contributions!

Comment: All TVs are different. Find the schematic of the one you are using and we’ll have something to work from.

Comment: Quick sanity-check - with the deflection coils reconnected and the TV operating as-normal, is there now a little dead spot in the middle which wasn't there before ... ?

Comment: @Kartman I will find the model and schematic this evening

Comment: @brhans No dead spot so far I'm aware that the phosphors could burn if there's too much beam irradiance. It really is not bright at all and can't be modulated by the brightness controls

Comment: Sounds like you need a separate horizontal deflection circuit with its own coil, off the CRT, to generate the acceleration voltage.

Comment: The 20,000 to 40,000 VDC for cathode on many TV's is generated from the flyback transformer, i.e., part of the ~15 kHz  horizontal drive system. In addition to the acceleration voltage, older sets also used a ~1,5 VAC secondary to power the filament of a vacuum tube high-voltage rectifier. You'll need a source of HV DC. Also, magnetic oscilloscopes have very limited frequency response, fine for a narrow-band audio demo, but not much else.

Comment: @Kartman I have added the circuit diagram now - a high quality pdf can also be accessed here https://www.radiomuseum.org/r/swing_calypso_tvp_2770.html

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks for your answer, I don't quite understand everything you're writing or at least the implications of it. Are you saying that the horizontal coil is part of the flyback transformer so no high voltage is being generated, or, cutting the horizontal circuit makes an open circuit which means that the flyback isn't connected. If it's the latter case then something with a similar resistance should resume normal function of the circuit. I think my tv is from the 80s so I guess not the vacuum tube rectifier? I have included the circuit diagram above now.

Comment: You'll need the schematic for this TV, and be able to *understand* what the components do, to make this work.

Comment: What happens if you just disconnect the horizontal or vertical coil? Does the CRT heater glow bright yellow? What voltage do you get on the CRT pins 2, 5, 6 and 7 relative to ground?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I think I will be able to understand - it is definitely not my area of expertise but I know the symbols for the components and their individual function and will do extra research around any suggestions. Just looking for some expert advice to help me get started